How do I hide the size of GPG message?
When constructing encrypted GPG messages I've noticed that the size of the output seems to be correlated to the size of the input. This makes sense in an information-theoretic sense. However, this is not ideal if I want to hide the length of a message. I imagine that the best you can do is pick a size N and produce cyphertext that pads out the input so the adversary knows the message must be less than length N, but has no information as to what  size between 0 and N bytes the input message is.
I see a --max-output and --input-size-hint option, but neither of those seems right unless I'm misreading the docs.
I'd prefer not to handle this padding (and unpadding) myself, as it seems likely I'll get it wrong and leak some info.
I'm currently using gpg 2.2.27, is there any option to do this, or is there a standard recipe? Ideally I would like to run something like:
RECPIENT_FINGERPRINT=4AC8B478335ED6ED667715F3622BE571405441B4
gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com $RECPIENT_FINGERPRINT
echo "mymessage" | gpg --encrypt --armor --recipient $RECPIENT_FINGERPRINT

But have the output appear as if the message is much larger than 9 characters.
